Force check string/array input for size
I want to read an string/array from the terminal/keyboard and write it to an string variable.
That's easy:
printf("Please enter the string now ... \n") ;
scanf("%s", str1)

But I also want to be sure that the string/array is not bigger than a certain size. But my approach doesn't work at all and the user can produce a buffer overflow.
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>

    #define MAX_STRG 10


    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

       char str1[MAX_STRG/2]="One", str2[MAX_STRG/2]="Two" ;
       int pos = 0, check = 1 ;
       size_t lenstr = 0 ;

      /* get the string   */
       while(check==1){
          printf("Please enter the first string now ... \n") ;
          scanf("%5s", str1) ;

          printf("Please enter the second string now ... \n") ;
          scanf("%5s", str2) ;

     /* string size in bytes*/
          lenstr = sizeof(str1) + sizeof(str2) ;

          printf("\n string1 string2 position StrgLen\n %s\t %s\t %d\t %d \n\n", str1, \
str2, pos, (int)lenstr) ;


          if (lenstr<=MAX_STRG+1){
             check = 0 ;
           }
       }

My check is too late and the string will already be written to memory. I thought giving the size with the scanf statement would do the check but no.
In general, I would like to find a way to enter a string within defined length boundaries and if the string is too large an error is produced.

Check the string length with strlen rather than sizeof.

Use fgets() or posix getline(), not scanf().

"That's easy".  Well, it is sort of easy, but your example is flawed.  scanf("%s", str1); is pretty much the canonical example of the worst possible way to read a string.  If you're going to use scanf, there are (at least) 2 major considerations.  Bound the input, and check the return value.  eg char str1[128]; ...; if (scanf("%127", str1) == 1) ...

See How to prevent scanf() causing a buffer overflow in C? See also A Beginner's Guide Away From scanf() and scanf() leaves the newline character in the input buffer.

Checked the Beginner`'s Guide which is a very good read.

The define can be stringified to be used in a format string to limit the number of characters. The %s specifier will append a terminating zero to the input so the limit in the format string must be one less than the buffer size.
The scanset "%*[^\n]" will scan and discard everything that is not a newline.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_STRG 4
// stringify to use in format string
#define FS(x) SFS(x)
#define SFS(x) #x


int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

   char str1[MAX_STRG + 1] = "One"; // +1 for terminating zero
   char str2[MAX_STRG + 1] = "Two";
   int pos = 0;
   int check = 1 ;
   size_t lenstr = 0 ;

  /* get the string   */
    printf ( "Please enter the first string now ... \n") ;
    if ( 1 != scanf ( "%"FS(MAX_STRG)"s", str1)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "scanf problem\n");
        return 1;
    }

    scanf ( "%*[^\n]"); // scan and discard everything not a newline

    printf ( "Please enter the second string now ... \n") ;
    if ( 1 != scanf ( "%"FS(MAX_STRG)"s", str2)) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "scanf problem\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* string size in bytes*/
    lenstr = strlen ( str1) + strlen ( str2) ;

    printf ( "\n string1 string2 position StrgLen\n %s\t %s\t %d\t %d \n\n"
    , str1
    , str2
    , pos
    , (int)lenstr) ;
}


You can use use stdin :
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUF_LEN 124
#if BUF_LEN < 2
# error "BUF_LEN need to be >= 2"
#endif

int main(void)
{
        char buf[BUF_LEN];
        ssize_t read_value;

        read_value = read(0, buf, BUF_LEN - 1); // read BUF_LEN - 1 bytes in stdin
        if (read_value == -1)
                return (1);

        buf[read_value] = '\0';

        printf("Input     : %s\n", buf);
        printf("Input len : %lu\n", strlen(buf));
        return (0);
}

Be clever, you can do multiple call to read.
Concatenate things with your buffer.
for more info check the man

Using file descriptor I/O (read() etc) is probably not the best way to go.  Doubly so if you ever use file stream I/O (getchar() etc) on the same source (standard input — stdin and STDIN_FILENO aka 0).  Also, the behaviour of read() will cause confusion if the input is ever a file or pipe instead of the terminal — it doesn't know what a line is.

 if(scanf("%4s", str1) == 1){ ... 

this will not cut off excess input string but will stop reading it from stdin after 4 characters. The excess part of the string is not discarded but will be put automatically into the next scanf.
if(scanf("%4s", str1) == 1){
         printf("->str1 is : %s\n", str1) ;
       }
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) ;

The additional while loop at the end will discard any excess input from the first scanf and the second scanf can get an new input
That solution is working for me.
